# how to run previous code before a message box pops up?

Tags: messagebox

I have the below Excel VBA code. The problem that I have is the part of the code starting "rows(x).select". When I step through the code the line is selected before the next message box pops up, however when I run the code the line is selected after the message box pops up. Is there any thing I can do to select the line before the message box pops up?

```vb
Sub deletedata()
    Dim x As String, y As Integer, z As Integer
    y = Range("auditstart").Row
    z = Range("auditend").Offset(-3, 0).Row
    x = InputBox("Please enter the row number which you wish to delete", "DELETE DATA")
    If Not IsNumeric(x) Then
    MsgBox "please enter a valid number"
    Exit Sub
    ElseIf CLng(x) < y Or CLng(x) > z Then
    MsgBox "Please enter a row number between " & y & " and " & z
    Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Rows(x).Select
    
    If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete row " & x & " ?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
    
    Exit Sub
    Else
    Cells(x, 3).Select
    Worksheets("audit").Unprotect password
    ActiveCell = "DELETE"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3) = 0
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4) = 0
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5) = 0
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6) = 0
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7) = Range("counter").Value + 1
    Sheets("colours").Unprotect password
    Range("counter").Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Value
    Sheets("colours").Protect password
    Worksheets("audit").Protect password
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: What's this? Visual Basic?

Answer (score 0):

Compare CLong against CLong for this line:

```
ElseIf CLng(x) < CLng(y) Or CLng(x) > CLng(z)
```

Order then seems to be ok. I have put Password in "" as i assume it is a string being passed. Not a variable called Password.

```
Option Explicit
Sub deletedata()
    Dim x As String, y As Integer, z As Integer
    y = Range("auditstart").Row
    z = Range("auditend").Offset(-3, 0).Row
    x = InputBox("Please enter the row number which you wish to delete", "DELETE DATA")

    If Not IsNumeric(x) Then
        MsgBox "please enter a valid number"
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf CLng(x) < CLng(y) Or CLng(x) > CLng(z) Then
        MsgBox "Please enter a row number between " & y & " and " & z
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Rows(x).Select

    If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete row " & x & " ?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Cells(x, 3).Select
        Worksheets("audit").Unprotect "Password"
        ActiveCell = "DELETE"
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3) = 0
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4) = 0
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5) = 0
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6) = 0
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7) = Range("counter").Value + 1
        Sheets("colours").Unprotect "Password"
        Range("counter").Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Value
        Sheets("colours").Protect "Password"
        Worksheets("audit").Protect "Password"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: the code is working fine, does not need editing. What is the problem is that the messagebox from the line: If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete row " & x & " ?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
        Exit Sub

Comment: runs before executing the line rows(x).select

Comment: I want the user to see the line selected when the messagebox appears

Comment: If you step through the code with F8 it executes in the correct order. Arrange the code window side by side with the spreadsheet tab of interest. See here https://ufile.io/mpqwb    If you execute from a button push the user will see the row highlighted, the problem may be if you are executing from VBE.

Comment: hi i know i already that if you step through with F8 it runs correctly, as stated in my original message. The problem is how to get it to run the same way when it is run normally or with a command button which calls the sub